# Json error while trying to parse data in java for android

Tags: java, android, json

I'am having problem with parsing my data through json i keep getting this error message. My program was working fine yesterday but today i keep on getting this error message.

```
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after main at character 6 of {main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_connect\selectUser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\selectUser.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): </table></font>
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): <br />
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\selectUser.php on line <i>18</i></th></tr>
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0030</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>252360</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_connect\selectUser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\selectUser.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
02-15 06:09:28.112: E/JSON Parser(1130): </table></font>


    }
```

I'm trying to make a log in which will allow the user based on there 'type' i.e admin or normal. To gain access to different gui. My program was working fine yesterday but today the program seems to be broken.

Comment: You don't get a JSON response, but an error page (HTML), which can of course not be parsed. So it's not necessarily your program which is broken.

Comment: Have you checked your json data? check here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @BBdev yeh my Json is valid

Comment: @qqilihq do you know the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

From your logcat output it looks like the source URL is no longer returning correct JSON. Maybe the format of the URL changed, or the API changed.

I think there are two things to fix here:

1. Look for the documentation to make the necessary changes to your request.
2. Make the app handle errors more gracefully instead of just crashing. I think you should check the HTTP response codes and also JSON parsing errors.